# Python - regex, blank element at the end of the list?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, split

I have a code

```
print(re.split(r"[\s\?\!\,\;]+", "Holy moly, feferoni!"))
```

which results

```
['Holy', 'moly', 'feferoni', '']
```

How can I get rid of this last blank element, what caused it?
If this is a dirty way to get rid of punctuation and spaces from a string, how else can I write but in regex?

Comment: First of all, there is no need to escape those characters in a character class `[\s?!,;]+`. You could also try matching instead of splitting by just making a negative character class `[^\s?!,;]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what @HamZa said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143011/python-regex-blank-element-at-the-end-of-the-list#comment35386624_23143011), you would use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and a negative character set:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> findall(r"[^\s?!,;]+", "Holy moly, feferoni!")
['Holy', 'moly', 'feferoni']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

the first thing which comes to my mind is something like this:

```
>>> mystring = re.split(r"[\s\?\!\,\;]+", "Holy moly, feferoni!")
['Holy', 'moly', 'feferoni', '']
>>> mystring.pop(len(mystring)-1)

>>> print mystring
['Holy', 'moly', 'feferoni']
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the empty string as the last element of you list, because the RegEx splits after the last `!`. It ends up giving you what's before the `!` and what's after it, but after it, there's simply nothing, i.e. an empty string! You might have the same problem in the middle of the string if you didn't wisely add the `+` to your RegEx.

Add a call to `list` if you can't work with an iterator. If you want to elegantly get rid of the optional empty string, do:

```
filter(None, re.split(r"[\s?!,;]+", "Holy moly, feferoni!"))
```

This will result in:

```
['Holy', 'moly', 'feferoni']
```

What this does is remove every element that is not a `True` value. The filter function generally only returns elements that satisfy a requirement given as a function, but if you pass `None` it will check if the value itself is `True`. Because an empty string is `False` and every other string is `True` it will remove every empty string from the list.

Also note I removed the escaping of special characters in the character class, as it is simply not neccessary and just makes the RegEx harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
__import__('re').findall('[^\s?!,;]+', 'Holy moly, feferoni!')
```